# Make new user data (collective.example.data) visible

Tags: plone

I followed the collective.examples.userdata directive to add fields to member and I works very fine.
The new infos are well stored and visible in the @@personal-information but now I'd like to go to the next step and show the new fields in the author.cpt page to make the new fields visible for every members(in a site directory for instance). 
I think I need to customize the membershiptool.getUserInfo() function but I just don't now how to proceed. 
Anyone knows how could I do to show this new fields in the author.cpt ?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I finally achieve this by overriding author.cpt in the skin folder of my product.I access my new fields with this : member.getProperty('my_new_field')